# This keeps coming back

Tags: pattern, lateral-thinking

Find the appropriate fillers for the blanks...

jafe, maap, maju, ____, ____, node

Hint:

> The title says it loud and clear! ;)

Answer (score 10, accepted):

The answer is:

> juau, seoc

---

### Explanation:

> The first two letters of the twelve months.

Comment: As I was hitting submit, the notification that an answer had been posted came up.

Comment: Correct,both of you,...although that was an easy one but the answers came faster than I expected.